# Firefox: center flex box

Tags: firefox, center, flexbox

I have the following code for my webpage, and when I use it in Chrome every thing is fine, but when I use it in Firefox the style is changed.
I need to make the Firefox style same like Chrome style, so any suggestion for that?
I mention in the code below what I tried to do.

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #86B3E6;
    color: 2F62AC;
    display: block;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    direction:rtl;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
a
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: 2F62AC;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    direction:rtl;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: none;
    padding: 12px 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
a.option1
{
    //Not centered but filled all area
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
}
a.option2
{
    //Not centered and not filled all area
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    display: -moz-box;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-align: center; */
}
a:active, a:hover {
    background-color: #2F62AC;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div><a class="option1" href="#">Option 1</a></div>
<div><a class="option2" href="#">Option 2</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Best regards.

Comment: I think you wanted to tag this with Flexbox; which is for the "CSS thing".  Flex is used for the Adobe/Apache UI Framework.

Comment: Could you give another description of what, exactly, the issue is and what you are trying to accomplish? Its not clear from your css comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need Flexbox for this purpose:  just `display: block` on your anchor:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/ocotcmpf

```
div
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #86B3E6;
    color: 2F62AC;
    display: block;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    direction:rtl;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
a
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: 2F62AC;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    direction:rtl;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: none;
    padding: 12px 10px;
    text-align: center;
  display: block; /* here */
}
a:active, a:hover {
    background-color: #2F62AC;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```